# Remove RePast buttons from all Eclipse-perspectives not related to RePast

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, toolbar

I use Eclipse for a lot of programming and coding-purposes. [RePast](http://repast.sourceforge.net) is (going to be) one of them.

I just installed RePast to Eclipse Helios using the Eclipse Update Manager.

Now I have those RePast buttons in every Eclipse perspective, even in those that are not related to RePast (for example the CVS Explorer or the PHP Editor). That irritates me a lot. RePast shouldn’t spread through my whole installation of Eclipse but stay in those perspectives related to RePast.

Is there a quick and easy way to remove those RePast buttons from all perspectives not related to RePast?

Thank you in advance!

(P.S.: there should be a "repast" tag on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Customize Perspective Dialog and uncheck the RePast contributions. The tough part is to do it in every perspective.

Simplest stuff is to should raise a bug against RePast and ask them to stop doing it ;-)

Comment: removing it from **every** perspective was also my first guess. However RePast is somehow crossing the border between helpful application and adware by polluting all my perspectives with their buttons.