# put an eclipse plugin under quarantine (or sandbox it)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sandbox

I already posted my problems with Repast Simphony here:

[Remove RePast buttons from all Eclipse-perspectives not related to RePast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651572/remove-repast-buttons-from-all-eclipse-perspectives-not-related-to-repast)

The development team of Repast Simphony kindly promised to take my suggestions into account for the next release. However, I want a solution now :)

As I am currently reinstalling Eclipse (to update to v 3.7) I asked myself if there was a possibility to "sandbox" plugins. Maybe there is a way to have two start modes: (1) with Repast Simphony, (2) with all other plugins.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked into any of the details on a Repast Simphony installation, but often what you want is easier done with two Eclipse installations that share the same workspace.

To make the scaled down version you must make a copy of the original and remove all the features you don't want.

Comment: good idea, but that makes 2x about 200 mb. not too much nowadays, but redundant data should always be avoided. However, that concept could maybe be enhanced with symlinks...

Comment: If you dive deep into p2, you will find that you can actually share the plug-ins between installations. I cannot help you there though as it is rather difficult :-)